# Issue to set random message in alert body every day on local notification iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nscalendar, nstimeinterval

I used the following code to generate random message from myArray(NSArray) every day at 8:00 AM using Local notification. but its do not work. I will get same message every day i.e, If today i get "Test 3" then the next day at 8:00 AM i will get same message like "Test 3". I want to generate random message from that array.

I don't know what is the problem in my code. Bellow is my sample code to generate random message:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

// Get the current date
 NSDate *Systemdate = [NSDate date];


// Break the date up into components
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:Systemdate];

// Set up the fire time
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:8];

// Notification will fire in one minute
[dateComps setMinute:0];
[dateComps setSecond:0];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
[dateComps release];


NSArray *myArry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Test 1", @"Test 2",@"Test 3",@"Test 4",@"Test 5",@"Test 6", nil];

id randomObj = nil;
int randomIndex;
if([myArry count]>0){

    randomIndex = arc4random() % [myArry count];
    randomObj = [myArry objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
}


UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;


// Notification details
localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", randomObj];


localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


// Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"View Alert";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

// Specify custom data for the notification
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

// Schedule the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

Thanks in adv..!!

Comment: Your code looks OK to me.  What do you do with `randomObj`?

Comment: Its generate random object from that array.

Comment: Well the code is correct so I want to know what you do with the selected string that makes you think it's not working.  I think that is where the error lies.

Comment: I dont know how to set alertBody as generate random message from that array everyday at 8:00 AM. Can you please tell me how to manage that alertBody as i want..??

Comment: Everyday i get same message like "Test 4". I want random.

Comment: You said in your question was that you get the same message every day, but it sounds like you have a different issue.  Show the code where you call the alert view.

Comment: No.  I don't see why you get the same string.  So show more code.

Comment: I used the same code which i integrated nothing more.

Comment: @Jigs, I too facing same issue, got stuck with this, do you have a solution to implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here "localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;", you are rescheduling the same notification every day and this is why you have the same content. If you want to have a different text each time you would have to create a separate notification objects for each random value and schedule them manually. For example you can schedule 10 or more events, save the last scheduled date in user default and make some logic to reschedule another 10 or more 2 day before your last save date or something like that.
You need to test this, in theory it looks good and it should work. Hope this helps.